# $λ_n\to0$; is $\sum λ_{n} e^{- | x-n |}$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $(λ_n)$ be a sequence that converges to zero. Is the series $\sum λ_{n} e^{- | x-n |} $ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Use that $\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-|x-y|} dy<\infty$ for all $x$ to show that $\sum e^{-|x-n|}<\infty$ for all $x$. The result then follows.